# NullPointerException returning array from method

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I have a table 2x2 (2 columns and 2 rows filled) on my database, I'm trying to get the entire table to my array, but when I try to print the result on the console I get *NullPointerException*. I can't figure out what I am missing.

Main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    mySQLManager Manager = new mySQLManager();
    Manager.Connect();
    String[] Dispositivos = null;
    Dispositivos = Manager.GetDevices();
    for (int i = 0; i < Dispositivos.length; i++){
        System.out.println(Dispositivos[i]);
    }
    Manager.Disconnect();
}
```

Method:

```
public String[] GetDevices(){
    String[] Devices = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM devices";
    int index = 0;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next()){
            Devices[index + 0] = resultSet.getString(1);
            Devices[index + 1] = resultSet.getString(2);
            index+=2;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("\nNão foi possivel ler os dispositivos do database");
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return Devices;
}
```

Error I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   logictesting.mySQLManager.GetDevices(mySQLManager.java:130)   at
>   logictesting.LogicTesting.main(LogicTesting.java:29) Java Result: 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Devices` is `null` in:

```
        Devices[index + 0] = resultSet.getString(1);
        Devices[index + 1] = resultSet.getString(2);
```

The easiest fix might be to turn `Devices` into an `ArrayList` since then it would be easy to grow it dynamically.

```
public String[] GetDevices(){
    List<String> Devices = new ArrayList<String>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM devices";
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next()){
            Devices.add(resultSet.getString(1));
            Devices.add(resultSet.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("\nNão foi possivel ler os dispositivos do database");
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return Devices.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: I am wondering does `index+0` really make any sense in OPs code?

Comment: Wrap the strings into an object and insert them into the list, this makes the consuming code better as well probably

Answer (score 2):

initialize **Devices** array before inserting elements in it.

```
public String[] GetDevices(){
    String[] Devices = new String[size];
```

If you don't know the size of the array before inserting the elements, its better to go for dynamic array such as ArrayList instead

Answer (score 1):

Both the arrays (Devices the current cause of null pointer and the array Dispositivos as well needs to be initialized) are null; initialize your arrays before using them.

Also I would suggest wrapping your two string values into an object and then using a list of this object - the code will look much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`String[] Devices = null;` You are not initialized devices .  And inserting value into an null `Devices[index + 0]` throws `NullPointerException` . Better you can try this . Because  arrays are fixed one .

```
public String[] GetDevices(){
    List<String> Devices = new ArrayList<String>();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM devices";
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next()){
            Devices.add(resultSet.getString(1));
            Devices.add(resultSet.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("\nNão foi possivel ler os dispositivos do database");
        System.out.print(ex.getMessage());

    }
    return Devices.toArray(new String[Devices.size()]);
}
```